# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los elementos de una lista circular doble, dado un boolean como parámetro?

Tags: java

gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

En este momento tengo la necesidad de mostrar únicamente los elementos dentro de una lista que coincidan con un parámetro booleano, mi lista es una lista circular doble y la misma no está compuesta por las estructuras más comunes, es una lista circular doble por así decirlo creada de forma manual.

Como mencioné necesito diseñar un método dentro de mi clase **Lista** que imprima los elementos que coincidan con un parámetro, de esta manera mi lista está compuesta por superhéroes que tienen o no capa.

Desde el **main** mando a llamar todos los métodos solicitados, y es donde tengo estructurada mi lista, a continuación de lo que se compone el **main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lista l = new Lista();
    l.inserta(new Superheroe ("Batman", "Masculino", "DC", 80, true));
    l.inserta(new Superheroe ("Superman", "Masculino", "DC", 90, true));
    l.inserta(new Superheroe ("Wonder Woman", "Femenino", "DC", 25, false));
    l.inserta(new Superheroe ("Spiderman", "Masculino", "MARVEL", 30, 
false));
    l.inserta(new Superheroe ("Ironman", "Masculino", "MARVEL", 30, false));
    System.out.println("---LISTA ORIGINAL---\n");
    System.out.println(l.toString());
    System.out.println("---VALIDA SI EXISTE UN SUPER HEROE---\n");
    System.out.println(l.existe("Ironman"));
    System.out.println(l.existe("Aquaman"));
    System.out.println("---MODIFICA SEGÚN EDAD DE SUPER HEROE---\n");
    l.modifica(new Superheroe("Sirenoman", "Masculino", "Nickelodeon", 25, 
true));
    System.out.println("LISTA MODIFICADA");
    System.out.println("\n" +l);
    System.out.println("---ELIMINA SEGÚN NOMBRE Y UNIVERSO---\n");
    l.elimina("Ironman", "MARVEL");
    System.out.println("LISTA DESPUÉS DE LA ELIMINACIÓN\n");
    System.out.println(l);
    l.elimina("Flash", "DC");
    System.out.println("---IMPRIME DE MANERA DESCENDENTE---\n");
    l.imprimeDesendente();
    System.out.println("---IMPRIME LOS SUPERHEROE CON CAPA O SIN CAPA---");
    l.cuentaHeroe(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

Como verán tengo distintos métodos con ellos no tengo problema alguno, dichos métodos están dentro de una clase **Lista** que detallo a continuación:

```
public class Lista {
private Nodo cabeza, ultimo;

public void inserta(Superheroe sh){
    //Valida si la lista esta vacia, si lo está se crea un nuevo nodo para 
guardar sh
    if (cabeza == null){
        cabeza = new Nodo(sh); //Se crea un nodo porque no se puede cargar sh porque es de tipo Superheroe
        ultimo = cabeza; //Al ser el 1er dato el último también es el primero     
    }else{ //Si no está vacía valora si la edad del super heroe es menor a la ya ingresada, si lo es, //acomoda los menores a la izquierda
        if (sh.getEdad() < cabeza.getDato().getEdad()){
            Nodo aux = new Nodo(sh);
            aux.setNext(cabeza); //el nuevo dato agregado tiene de siguiente a cabeza               
            cabeza.setBack(aux); //y cabeza tiene de anterior a aux (el nuevo dato)
            cabeza = aux; //el nuevo dato de primero 
        }else{ //Si el valor a ingresar no tiene una edad menor al ya ingresado, acomoda los valores a la derecha
            if (sh.getEdad() > ultimo.getDato().getEdad()){
                Nodo aux = new Nodo (sh); //une los datos
                aux.setBack(ultimo); //aux tiene de anterior a ultimo
                ultimo.setNext(aux); //ultimo tiene de siguiente a aux
                ultimo = aux;
            }else{ //Agrega todos los valores restantes
                Nodo aux = cabeza;
                //Mientras la edad sea mayor que la del siguiente del aux
                while(sh.getEdad() > aux.getNext().getDato().getEdad()){
                    //Avanza en el ciclo
                    aux = aux.getNext();
                }
                //nuevo nodo con toda la info del super heroe
                Nodo temp = new Nodo (sh);
                temp.setNext(aux.getNext());
                temp.setBack(aux);
                aux.setNext(temp);
                temp.getNext().setBack(temp);
            }
        }            
    }
    //se crea la lista circular en ambos sentidos
        ultimo.setNext(cabeza); //ultimo tiene como siguiente a cabeza
        cabeza.setBack(ultimo); //cabeza tiene como anterior a ultimo
}//fin del método inserta

public boolean existe (String nombre){
    String mensaje;
    boolean existe = false;
    Nodo aux = cabeza;
    if (cabeza == null) {
        mensaje = "La lista no contiene datos";
    } else {
        if (nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre())) {
            existe = true;
        }aux = aux.getNext();
        while (aux != cabeza) {
            if (nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre())) {
                existe = true;
            }
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
    }
    return existe;
```

}

```
public void modifica (Superheroe sh){
    String mensaje;
    Nodo aux = cabeza;
    boolean existe = false;
    if (cabeza == null) { //Valida si la lista está o no vacía
        mensaje = "La lista no contiene datos";
    }else{
        if (sh.getEdad() == aux.getDato().getEdad()) { //valida si la edad ingresa corresponde a alguna de la lista
            aux.getDato().setNombre(sh.getNombre());
            aux.getDato().setGenero(sh.getGenero());
            aux.getDato().setUniverso(sh.getUniverso());
            aux.getDato().setEdad(sh.getEdad());
            aux.getDato().setCapa(sh.isCapa());
            existe = true; //Se coloca en true para indicar que se encontraron datos que cambiar
        }aux = aux.getNext();
        while (aux != cabeza){ //Mientras que aux sea diferente de cabeza, se hará el if, esto nos permite recorrer la lista
            if (sh.getEdad() == aux.getDato().getEdad()) { //valida si la edad ingresa corresponde a alguna de la lista
            aux.getDato().setNombre(sh.getNombre());
            aux.getDato().setGenero(sh.getGenero());
            aux.getDato().setUniverso(sh.getUniverso());
            aux.getDato().setCapa(sh.isCapa());
            existe = true; //Se coloca en true para indicar que se encontraron datos que cambiar
            }aux = aux.getNext();
        }
        if (existe == false) {
        System.out.println("No existe un superheroe con esa edad");
        }   
    }
}

public void elimina (String nombre, String universo){
    String mensaje;
    Nodo aux = cabeza;
    boolean existe = false;
    if (cabeza == null) { //Valida si la lista está o no vacía
        mensaje = "La lista no contiene datos";
    }else{//empieza a validad los elementos que componen la lista para encontrar los parametros ingresados
        if (nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre()) && universo.equals(aux.getDato().getUniverso())){
            cabeza = aux.getNext();
            existe = true;
        }if (nombre.equals(aux.getBack().getDato().getNombre()) && universo.equals(aux.getBack().getDato().getUniverso())){
            ultimo = ultimo.getBack();
            existe = true;
        }if (nombre.equals(aux.getNext().getDato().getNombre()) && universo.equals(aux.getNext().getDato().getUniverso())){
            aux.setNext(aux.getNext().getNext());
            aux.getNext().setBack(aux);
            existe = true;
        }aux = aux.getNext();
        while (aux != cabeza){ //Mientras que aux sea diferente de cabeza, se hará el if, esto nos permite recorrer la lista
            if (nombre.equals(aux.getNext().getDato().getNombre()) && universo.equals(aux.getNext().getDato().getUniverso())){
                aux.setNext(aux.getNext().getNext());
                aux.getNext().setBack(aux);
                existe = true;
            }aux = aux.getNext();
        }
        //Con lo siguiente se conforma la lista de manera circular doble
        ultimo.setNext(cabeza);
        cabeza.setBack(ultimo);
        //si no existe el super héroe con los parametros indicados nos devuelve que no existe
        if (existe == false) {
        System.out.println("No existe un super héroe con dicho nombre y que pertenezca a dicho universo");
        }
    }
}

public void imprimeDesendente (){
    String mensaje = "";
    boolean existe = false;
    if (cabeza == null) { //Valida si la lista está o no vacía
        mensaje = "La lista no contiene datos \n";
    }else{
        Nodo auxiliar = ultimo;
        mensaje += auxiliar + ", \n";
        auxiliar = auxiliar.getBack();
        while (auxiliar != ultimo){
            mensaje += auxiliar + ", \n";
            auxiliar = auxiliar.getBack();

        }
    }
    System.out.println(mensaje);
}

public void cuentaHeroe (Boolean capa){
    String mensaje = "";
    boolean existe = false;
    if (cabeza == null) { //Valida si la lista está o no vacía
        mensaje = "La lista no contiene datos \n";
    }else{
        if (capa.equals(capa)){
            System.out.println(capa.equals(capa.toString()));
        }
    }
}



    @Override
public String toString() {
    Nodo aux = cabeza;
    String s = "Lista: \n";
    if (aux != null) {
        s += aux + ", \n";
        aux = aux.getNext();
        while (aux != cabeza) {
            s += aux + ", \n";
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
    } else {
        s+= "Vacia";
    }
    return s;
}
```

}

Es en el método **public void cuentaHeroe** donde estoy teniendo inconvenientes porque lo que necesito es que imprima todos los superhéroes que tienen o no capa según lo que ingrese como parámetro desde el **main**, al llamar al método únicamente me devuelve un valor false, sé que hay un error dentro de la lógica de ese método pero no logro determinar cuál es, agradecería cualquier ayuda al respecto.

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno luego de leer tus recomendaciones y meterle un ojo a la lógica del método que tal y como dices no decía nada, el método quedó de la siguiente manera.

```
public void cuentaHeroe(Boolean capa) {
    String mensaje = "   ";
    boolean existe = true;
    Nodo aux = cabeza;
    if (cabeza == null) {
        mensaje = "La lista está vacía";
    } else {
        if (aux.getDato().isCapa() == capa){
            System.out.println(aux.getDato().getNombre());
        }
        aux = aux.getNext();
        while (aux != cabeza){                 
            if (aux.getDato().isCapa() == capa){
                System.out.println(aux.getDato().getNombre());
            }
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Dentro del main el método mandado a llamar valida en TRUE y en FALSE según corresponda.

```
public class FabianM_Tarea6 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("---IMPRIME LOS SUPERHEROE CON CAPA---");
    l.cuentaHeroe(Boolean.TRUE);
    System.out.println("---IMPRIME LOS SUPERHEROE SIN CAPA---");
    l.cuentaHeroe(Boolean.FALSE);
}
}
```

Y dentro de la consola, efectivamente imprime lo solicitado.

```
---IMPRIME LOS SUPERHEROE CON CAPA---
Sirenoman
Batman
Superman
---IMPRIME LOS SUPERHEROE SIN CAPA---
Spiderman
Robin
Ciclope
```

Answer (score 1):

No es que hay un error. Es que esta funcion no hace absolutamente nada.

```
public void cuentaHeroe (Boolean capa){
    String mensaje = "";
    boolean existe = false;
    if (cabeza == null) { //Valida si la lista está o no vacía
        mensaje = "La lista no contiene datos \n";
    }else{
        //Aca empiezan tus problemas. Primero deberias iterar tu lista, buscando los heroes con capa.
        //Sin embargo, preguntas si la variable que entro como parametro (capa) es igual a la variable que entro como parametro (?)
        if (capa.equals(capa)){
            //y aca, estas imprimiendo el resultado de la variable que entro como parametro, igualandola a la variable que entro como parametro pero transformada a string (algo que es falso, no son el mismo objeto).
            System.out.println(capa.equals(capa.toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Como ves, no estas haciendo nada. Vas a tener que refactorizar todo, para que haga lo que realmente queres que haga, que es recorrer la lista. cosa que ya hiciste en otros lugares por ahi.